# Dificuldade em posicionar objetos após @media (max-width: 320px) {

Tags: jquery, css3

Onde estou errando?

Tenho o `html` abaixo

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="_global/_funcoes/_js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

<button class="menuAbrir"><img  src="_img/btn-menu.png" width="50px;" title="Abrir Menu" /></button>
<nav class="menuNav">
  <a class="menuFechar"><img  src="_img/btn-close.png" width="30px;" title="Abrir Menu" /></a><br>
  <ul class="menuUlTopo">
    <li class="menuTopo"><a href="principal.php" title="Principal">Principal</a></li>
    <li class="menuTopo"><a href="administradoresMenu.php" title="Administradores">Administradores</a></li>
    <li class="menuTopo"><a href="clientesMenu.php" title="Clientes">Clientes</a></li>
    <li class="menuTopo"><a href="imoveisMenu.php" title="Imóveis">Imóveis</a></li>
    <li class="menuTopo"><a href="tiposMenu.php" title="Tipos de Imóveis">Tipos de Imóveis</a></li>
    <li class="menuTopo"><a href="emails.php?acao=listar" title="E-mails">E-mails</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(e){
  $(".menuAbrir").click(function() {
    $(".menuNav").show();
    $(".menuFechar").show();
  });

  $(".menuFechar").click(function() {
    $(".menuNav").hide();
    $(".menuAbrir").show();
  });
});
</script>
```

A ideia aqui é que quando chegar na resolução de `320px` x `480px` e só até ela, um botão apareça. Até aí ok.

O problema agora é que existe o `<button class="menuAbrir">` e `<nav class="menuNav">`

Não estou conseguindo posicionar o `botão` em `top:0` e `left:0` e nem o `<nav class="menuNav">` em `top 0`.

Mas consigo projetar o `<nav class="menuNav">` como 100% da tela pelo width, mas o heigth não.

Eis o `css`:

```
.menuAbrir {
     display:none;
}

.menuNav {
      display:block;
}

.menuFechar {
    display:none;
}

@media (max-width: 320px) {
 .menuAbrir {
     display:block;
     width:60px;
     height:60px;
     top:0;
 }

 .menuNav {
      display:none;
      position:fixed;
      top: 0;
      left:0;
      width: 100%;
      height:100%;
  }

  ul li.menuTopo a {
      width: 320px;
      height: 480px;
  }

  .menuFechar {
      float:right;
      cursor:pointer;
  }
}
```

Onde estou errando?

Comment: Já tentou colocar sua funcao jquery dentro de $(document).ready(function() { ...Seu codigo aqui });

Comment: Precisei mudar a pergunta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bem, em jQuery você precisa colocar código dentro do ready:

```
  $(document).ready(functional(e){
// seu código
});
```

Tente isso, se a resposta servir dê um up.

Comment: Até que funcionou. Mas observe que 
menuNav {
      display:none;
      position:relative;
      top: 0;
      width: 320px;
      height:480px;
  }
O menuNav não colou no topo do navegador ficando em cima de todos elementos. Qual o erro?

Comment: Precisei mudar a pergunta

Comment: Você tem certeza que quer usar o max-width, será que não é min-width que você quer usar? (estou respondendo do celular)

Comment: até a resolução de celular acatar as mudanças

Comment: Vc testou o para ver oq acontece se colocar o min-width? É que não tenho como testar agora...

Comment: sim, testei. A redução de resoluções está funcionando normalmente. O problema é que não consigo posicionar o menu no topo, fica um espaço abaixo até chegar no menu. Mesmo que faça top:0